# Fat-free-framework SESSION variables not accessible globally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, fat-free-framework

My website uses the Fat-free-framework, and I am attempting to use the f3 "SESSION" variables with the SQL handler to store a piece of user data after login and access it from a different part of the application. However, even though I can see that the session variables were set properly and show up in the SQL table, attempting to access them in a different function called by API just results in an empty string.

I have a function login() which is called to login the user, and I am attempting to store the user's login token in the session SQL table.

```
new \DB\SQL\Session($f3->get('db'),'sessions',true,function($session){return true;});
$f3->set('SESSION.token',$user->token);
```

I can access the variable just fine inside of the login() function:

```
error_log($f3->get('SESSION.token')); // This works
```

Now in a different function, login_check(), which is called by our API, I am trying to get the user token from the current session and use it to retrieve their user ID.

```
error_log('Found session token: ' . $f3->get('SESSION.token'));
$token = $f3->get('SESSION.token');
error_log($token); // This results in an empty string.
```

I can see in the SQL table's 'data' column that the user token along with some other session variables I set are present. Why am I unable to access them from anywhere else? There are several reroutes inbetween the calls to the two functions, but I was under the impression that SESSION variables would persist across redirects unlike the standard hive variables.

I experienced the same behavior when using the standard PHP session handler instead, by removing the call to "new \DB\SQL\Session()" and just using $f3->set(). Switching to SQL was an attempt to fix it, but I still experience the same problem. Could this be due to the API requests I am making in between functions, or an issue with the server configuration? I have been extremely stumped on this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: when the API request is made, make sure that the session cookie (`PHPSESSID`) is sent along with the request, otherwise PHP cannot find the Session you would like to open... 
API's are usually stateless and therefore mostly implement another type of authentication, like JWT or a simple custom auth header, rather than sticking on sessions.

Comment: Ok, that seems like it could be the cause of the problem. I can see that the cookie persists between redirects in the browser dev tools. Are you saying I should be sending it by POST alongside the other data for all the API requests? How would I do that and tell PHP to load that session? Does this still apply if I am using F3's SQL handler?

Comment: how do you make your api requests? is it just some javascript ajax with jquery or how is it implemented in the frontend? just make sure the session cookie is send along with the requests (cookie header)